# Is it possible to install OS over Quectel LTE 4G OR NB-IoT Modules?

Tags: lte, 4g, qualcomm, gsmcomm, quectel

I would like to install any OS with minimal functionality on the Quectel 4G-NB-IoT module (BG-96, BG-95-M3).

Will those modules support this features?

If yes: which OS should I prefer? (ANDROID, LINUX, Any Other).

Will you please help me to know more about this?

Answer (score 0):

It is purely dependent on the type of your application & requirement.   You may need to check the specification of the MDM model for support of Linux OS or threadX or other OS if any. Some MDM models support both Linux OS and threadX. The BG96 is based on MDM9206 which supports both Linux OS and ThreadX. BG95 is based on MDM9205 which supports ThreadX for sure.

Comment: You are right, As per the Qualcomm Documentation for the MDM9206 it's support both Linux OS and threadX. Those specification are related to the MDM9205/6 but, What about the Quectel modules? If I wants to use the linux OS on Quectel BG96 module what should I do? Dose it support Linux OS? If yes, How?.